# Cannot send headers; headers already sent error without any known changes to site, but possible update today

Tags: magento-1.9

Here is the correct error code, Version 1.9.1:

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/customer/www/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php, line 32

Trace:
#0 /home/customer/www/abc/public_html/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /home/customer/www/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
#2 /home/customer/www/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
#3 /home/customer/www/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
#4 /home/customer/www/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /home/customer/www/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /home/customer/www/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /home/customer/www/abc/public_html/index.php(103): Mage::run('base', 'website')
#8 {main}
```

What is frustrating is nothing has happened to this site for months, nobody has touched it.  But looking through the logs something tried to happen early hours of this morning:

```
2022-04-05 09:28:22 UTC [nginx][error] 79543#0: *33157383 openat() "/home/u558-baj60g34iomx/www/abc.com/public_html/.well-known/autoconfig/mail/autodiscover.xml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 81.130.224.19, server: abc.com, request: "POST /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml HTTP/1.1", host: "abc.com"

2022-04-05 02:04:23 UTC [apache][:notice] [pid 93365] [client 194.26.29.143:60440] mod_hive matched URI http://abc.co.uk/downloader/index.php (/home/u558-baj60g34iomx/www/abc.com/public_html/downloader/index.php) with match 12
```

So as I understand it, and not being any type of expert on Magento, this error is normally to do with a space. But without knowing what has been updated, or where to look to find any space I am a little lost.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?  This site needs to be fixed as soon as.

Many Thanks

Addy

Comment: have you checked your php version changed or same as before??

Comment: Hello, thank you for the idea. I am not sure what it was before, but I have returned it to 7.3.33.  It is an old Magneto so I am not sure what version of PHP Magneto 1.9.1 should be on.  Could this be the issue ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is any help, but on Chrome I get an 503 error on loading the reports.php?

Comment: Php version can possible reason.

Comment: Hello @GohilRajesh.  You are correct, our provider did a mass update of PHP and remove, completely, the old version the site worked on.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't respond in the comments because I don't have any reputation here but I was wondering if you ever solved this problem?